# Pandas style works on the notebook, but the HTML output doesn't seem to have the style. What is wrong with this situation?

Tags: html, css, pandas, styles

I am trying to display a pandas dataframe in an email, so I am using the to_html() function on a dataframe.

When I do this on jupyter, things are just fine..

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
result = df.style.format(precision=2).set_table_styles([{'selector' : 'td,th', 'props' : [('border', '1px solid lightgrey')]}])
```

[image: jupyter output]

But if I do

```
result.to_html()
```

and then paste the resulting HTML into a HTML Viewer I get the following. Without borders and with a lot of \n. So I am unable to print borders the email reports. What is going on? What should I do to get the borders displaying on to_html(). Is there another way to get the HTML? thank you for the help.

[image]

Comment: HI, when I copy the resulting html code to a file and preview it in a browser, borders are correctly rendered. What "HTML viewer" are you using?

Comment: You wanted `print(result.to_html())` inside the Jupyter notebook and then take what is shown in the output of the Jupyter cell. What you saw with `result.to_html()` was the string representation, hence all the newline symbols like `\n` and flanking quotes. Alternatively, in the notebook, you can send it to file like `result.to_html("styled_df.html")`. I suspect @Avery did one of those when running the code in Python and that is why it worked 'directly in Python'. Running just `result.to_html()` after import statements and OP code in a Python script didn't show me any output.

Answer (score 1):

You want to print the string in Jupyter, as presently illustrated in the Pandas documentation in the first code example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html?highlight=excel#More-About-CSS-and-HTML):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
result = df.style.format(precision=2).set_table_styles([{'selector' : 'td,th', 'props' : [('border', '1px solid lightgrey')]}])
print(result.to_html())
```

And then copy the output from that Jupyter cell.

Alternatively, write it to a file:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
result = df.style.format(precision=2).set_table_styles([{'selector' : 'td,th', 'props' : [('border', '1px solid lightgrey')]}])
result.to_html("my_html.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter is printing raw newline characters instead of displaying as actual newlines. The same thing happens for me (on linux, which might matter)

I ran a text replace to remove all the `\n` characters, and now it works.

Alternatively, I also get correct output to start with by running code directly in Python and not using jupyter.

Edit: I ended up handling my HTML styling outside of pandas.

There is some sort of **compatibility issue with Microsoft Outlook** (desktop) and it doesnt render correctly, although it is OK in Outlook365 and as standalone HTML in Chrome.

I am trying to highlight a row in yellow based on one cell, and in Outlook some cells are randomly not highlighted, and interesting side effect: **My table borders also don't show up**

On top of this, I have 1 cell that is bugged even outside of Outlook. The style attribute never gets created for it, for some reason.

Anyway, I gave up and am instead using Beautiful Soup to add my HTML styling. I have never used Beautiful Soup before, but got it done in 20 minutes after many hours of failure with Pandas.

```
html_table = df.to_html(index=False, classes='table table-bordered')


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_table,'html.parser')

# grab rows from my table
rows = soup.find("table", border=1).find("tbody").find_all("tr")
# we get to use normal python looping!
for row in rows:
    # grab the element I need to check
    last_col = row.find_all("td")[-1]
    # apply style
    if last_col.get_text() != '':
         row.attrs['style'] = 'background-color: yellow'
# Add table to the rest of my email
html_body += str(soup)
```

I didn't want to bring in another library at first, but wow was that easier.

Something more like your example, tested working in Outlook (I fiddled the styling a bit after testing in Outlook desktop and 365's darkmode):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
html_table = df.to_html(classes='table table-bordered')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_table,'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table", border=1)
elements = table.find_all(["td", "th"])

for e in elements:
    e.attrs['style'] = 'border: 2px solid lightgrey;'

# single line border
table.attrs['style'] = 'border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;'

html_body += str(soup)
```

Comment: What was your actual line in your Python script involving `result.to_html()` for running it 'directly in Python'? If you see my comment below the original post, you'll see I saw no output when I use `result.to_html()` as the last line. I had to add a filename or put it in `print()`. I was using Pandas version 1.4.4.

Comment: I probably wrapped it with print(), since without the interactive shell it doesn't output anything otherwise. 

I just noticed you mentioned email reports...are you viewing these in Outlook? Do they display wrong in the desktop client, but look fine in Outlook 365? That's something I'm running into.

I'm trying to highlight a row, and panda's is doing this by creating classes for every single cell, and outlook isnt handling it well for whatever reason. 
Additionally, I have a certain cell that never gets it attribute created, so even outside of Outlook it is still slightly wrong.

Comment: Well if you ARE using Outlook, I think I got it